# Get URL image content using php

Tags: php

I have a url like this.
http://www.cardekho.com/

If i wish to get all the image content(jpg,png,gif - only images) from this url to my local machine(C:\images) - How to do this..

Please help me.
Thanks -
Haan

Comment: There are much better solutions for this than PHP. Does it have to be PHP?

Comment: If you only want to do this once, how about fetching them from your browser cache?

Comment: @Pekka - Not only in php. It can be in any lang. Sample code wil be much appreciatable

Answer (score 0):

Use either cURL or PHP function file_get_content to get the source code and the source code for the css (if you want to get background-images aswell).

Then use preg_match_all and match all the image tags.

Loop all found image paths and use cURL or file_get_content to save the image to a local destination.